# Java inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, class

Why does is print last "I'm a Child Class." ?

```
public class Parent
{
    String parentString;
    public Parent()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent Constructor.");
    }

    public Parent(String myString)
    {
        parentString = myString;
        System.out.println(parentString);
    }

    public void print()
    {
       System.out.println("I'm a Parent Class.");
    }
} 

public class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child() {
        super("From Derived");
        System.out.println("Child Constructor.");
    }

    public void print()
    {
       super.print();
       System.out.println("I'm a Child Class.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.print();
        ((Parent)child).print();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
From Derived

Child Constructor.

I'm a Parent Class.

I'm a Child Class.

I'm a Parent Class.

I'm a Child Class.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because this is an example of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Java) (late binding). At compile time you specify that the object is of type `Parent` and therefore can call only methods defined in `Parent`. But at runtime, when the "binding" happens, the method is called on the object, which is of type `Child` no matter how it is referenced in the code.

The part that surprises you is why the overriding method should be called at runtime. In Java (unlike C# and C++) all methods are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) and hence the overriding method is called. See [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B) to understand the difference.

Comment: Good Question and good answer. This is also a good thing in real programs; your code could break if you by accident had some code that called the parent implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Both:

```
child.print();
```

and

```
((Parent)child).print();
```

Should return:

```
I'm a Parent Class.
I'm a Child Class.
```

In that order.

**Casting an object to its base class doesn't change which method call gets made.**

In this case, even after the cast, the child print method gets called and not the parent.

Comment: What confused me was that the same code in C# prints only "I'm Parent Class"

Comment: Inheritance and polymorphism works exactly the same way in C#. However, c# requires the virtual keyword for methods that you want overridden in inheriting subclasses, so I'm guessing that you didn't use virtual, hence you got the different result.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you cast child to Parent this does not change its implementation of the method. This does not actually make it a parent. This is why you can do something like:

```
Image img = new BufferedImage(...);
```

Even though Image is abstract img is still a bufferedImage underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are casting it as the Parent class, that does not mean it will use its parent's functions-- it will only treat the object as a Parent.

By saying ((Parent)child).print(); you are saying "Treat this object as a Parent Object, Not a Child Object".  Not "Use the parent method implementations"

Thus if the child object had other methods you wouldn't be able to call them.  But since print() is a method of the parent you can still call it, but it uses the actual object's (not the class its casted to) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

in java  if we call any method  on one object then its calls the method  by using sub most object ...............
here:

Object
|
|
Parent
|
|
Child <- sub most object

Case 1::

Child child = new Child();

```
    child.print();
```

this calling child class method print by using child object... child is sub most
so it prints

output::

I'm a Parent Class.
I'm a Child Class.

Explanation: From child method it is calling parent method because of super.print(); method 
so first line is I'm a Parent Class. after completion of parent method execution controls comes back to child method and prints  I'm a Child Class.

Case 2::

```
    ((Parent)child).print();
if we call like this jvm calls print () method by using sub most object here sub most  object is child object so it prints 

output::
          I'm a Parent Class.
          I'm a Child Class.
```

Explanation: From child method it is calling parent method because of super.print(); method 
so first line is I'm a Parent Class. after completion of parent method execution controls comes back to child method and prints  I'm a Child Class.