# invoking overloaded methods by casting classes with 'this' keyword

Tags: java, class, inheritance

This was a coding question given to me in my exam and i cant seem to figure out what's happening, would be helpful if someone could tell me whats happening :)

```
class A1 {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B1 extends A1 {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C1 extends B1 {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class D1 extends C1 {

    void m1() {
        System.out.println("D");
    }

    void m2() {
        m1();
        ((C1) this).m1();
        ((B1) this).m1();
        ((A1) this).m1();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new D1().m2();
    }

}
```

This produces the Output :

```
D
D
D
D
```

My Expected Output :

```
D
C
B
A
```

I'd like to know why even with the casting and the usage of 'this' keyword it's still calling the method inside the same class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506412/java-inheritance)

Comment: Because although you cast to that type your instance still is of the most derived one. So when you call `m1` also the most derived method is used whcih is defined in `D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the instance are still the same instance even if you tell the compiler to treat it like a super instance.

```
void m2() {
        m1();
        ((C1) this).m1();
        ((B1) this).m1();
        ((A1) this).m1();
    }
```

If you have a VW Polo and cast them all to Car, it's still a Polo and will still call it's own methods.