# Asking about Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

suppose I have a situation like:

```
class Base{

    public Base() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

}


class Derived extends Base{

    public Derived(){

      System.out.println("Devired");
    }
}


class DeriDerived extends Derived{
    public DeriDerived(){
      System.out.println("DeriDevired");
    }
}
```

I am not so clear how the inheritance work, for example if I try: `Derived b = new DeriDerived();` and `DeriDerived b1 = new DeriDerived();`, they both generated the same results.

For the second situation: `DeriDerived b1 = new DeriDerived();` What I understand (might be correct, maybe not???) that the *DeriDerived* will call its superclass which is *Derived*, and the *Devired* will call again its superclass which is *Base*, so at the end we will have result looklike: *Based/Devired/DeriDerived*.

But for the first situation I dont understand how it works to get the same result as *Based/Devired/DeriDerived*

Can anyone help to explain me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You call the same constructor in both examples. Why would it generate different results?

Comment: The type of the variable where you store the constructor result (the instance) don't impact the construction. It will only define the type of the box and then the properties accessible (method, variable). But you still create the same type of object, a `DeriDerived`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506412/java-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

Both objects are instances of deriderived, therefor they behave similarly.
they are only sharing the same constructor.
but if you have other methods in the classes you will only be able to access the methods in derived and base (in the first scenario), while in the second scenario you will be able to access all methods from parent classes.
doing this is not advised as it will bring some ambiguity to your code.

Answer (score 1):

In java the variable, which holds reference to the object does not impact the object creation.

In all cases you are calling `DeriDerived` constructor, but object created like so can be referenced by type of: DeriDerived, Devired, Base,Object.

But in each cases you have different method visibility.

So when you will create an instance of DeriDerived, but refer to it by Devired, you will have access only to methods from Devired and Base classes. You will not see methods from DeriDerived class, event though this will be a reference to the same object -> DeriDerived.

Answer (score 0):

when you create object

```
 Derived d=new DeriDerived()
```

internally default constructor has first statement is **super()**

The super keyword can also be used to invoke or call the parent class constructor. Constructor are calling from bottom to top and executing from top to bottom.so it work like following

1. DeriDerived() constructor  call to Derived()  constructor as DeriDerived 
   constructor first statement is super(), it call to parent constructor i.e 
   Derived () constructor.
2. Derived() constructor call to Base() constructor
3. Base() constructor call to object class constructor as object is parent class.

but executed in following hierarchy Base()--> Derived()--> DeriDerived()

Debug this code

```
class Base{

    public Base() {
         super();
        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}


class Derived extends Base{

    public Derived(){
     super();

      System.out.println("Devired");
    }
}


class DeriDerived extends Derived{
    public DeriDerived(){
       super();
      System.out.println("DeriDevired");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See in both objects creation 
**Derived b = new DeriDerived();** and **DeriDerived b1 = new DeriDerived();**

you are calling the same reference, does mean with the reference call, i.e, with b or b1, they both are creating same instances that is why they are giving same results.

If you want a difference then create public methods in each class and try to access with reference.

Using subclass reference, (i.e, using b1) you can able to access Derived class methods, but using super class reference (i.e, using b) you won't be able to access subclass (DeriDerived) class methods